# How can I properly format this equation in the title of my plot? (python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, syntax, latex

I am trying to add a title with the correct syntax to print the formula for a Gaussian distribution and don't see my mistake. Can someone help me spot it? My attempt is below and [produces this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRIqd.png) while the formula should look like f(x) = [*right hand side of this*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIiEt.png). I am asking for python3, though I think it's the same as LaTeX.

```
title = "Gaussian Distribution: f(x) = $\\frac{1/\sigma (2\pi)^{frac{1/2}}} \exp( \\frac{(x-\mu)^2 / 2\sigma^2} )"
plt.title(title)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MathText expressions must be enclosed by `$` signs.
They must be valid latex commands, i.e. an opening `{` must have a closing `}`.
Using raw strings makes escaping unnecessary.

```
title = r"f(x) =  $\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}  e^{\frac{(x-\mu)^2 }{ 2\sigma^2}}$"
```

[image]

Comment: "Using raw strings makes escaping unnecessary." What does that mean?

Comment: You don't need to use `\\ `, if you use raw strings. `"\\"` is equivalent to `r"\"`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I had used `\\ if a single `\ caused the next character to change color in my text editor (Atom).