# Print formula in plot

Tags: python, jupyter, sympy

Sympy returns a print of an expression in Jupyter in mathematical notation. E.g.:

```py
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot

x = symbols("x")

2 + 3 * x**2
```

will print: [image]

However, I can't include this in a plot title. If I run

```py
exp = 2 + 3 * x**2
plot(exp, title=exp)
```

it will print the expression in the Python notation: `2 + 3 * x**2`

Is there any way to get the mathematical notation shown in the plot?

Comment: Does [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096734/how-can-i-properly-format-this-equation-in-the-title-of-my-plot-python-3) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it that way

```py
from sympy import symbols, latex
from sympy.plotting import plot

x = symbols("x")
exp = 2 + 3 * x**2
plot(exp, title=rf'${latex(exp)}$')
```

`latex` write the expression as a latex formula. And you need to enclose latex formula with `$` so that sympy doesn't treat the title as raw text.

Comment: Nice, I had no idea that method existed! Thank you!

Comment: The `sympy.latex()` is documented [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/printing.html#mathrm-latex). For others not only plotting in Jupyter, you can also use the approach used to get the latex form in markdown in Jupyter with `display.Math()`, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/display-command-output-as-math-ipython-display-math/3125/3?u=fomightez) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76230099/8508004).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Indeed, you're right. I first tried without the `$`, and saw that the `$` wern't included in `latex()` output, so I added them with `+`. So the "incremental" history of that code explain why the `+`. But indeed, f-string are the fatest way to add the `$`, or to concatenate things generally speaking. Faster than `+`, faster than `.format`, faster than `%s`, etc. I updated my answer to use f-string as suggested.